# Integration of Azure with OKTA using OIDC

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, okta

We are working on Integrating Azure with Okta using OIDC. Here Azure acts as a IDP and Okta as a federation provider.

The requirement is accessing the protected resource via okta. Then OKTA will send a request to Azure AD for authentication. If its success, then it will redirected to the protected application.

How should we achieve it with the usage of OIDC?

Comment: Yes you can definitely do this with Okta via inbound federation. https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/azure/before-you-begin/ Please let me know if I can help further!

Answer (score 1):

If you find it quirky at all, here is a direct guide for setting things up on the Azure side for Okta: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/azure/create-an-app-at-idp/